# How to highlight the submenu item?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I've set up a menu and submenu structure in Joomla! 2.5

```
Car
  Mercedes
  Honda
Bicycle
  Canondale
  Pirelli
```

I've set up the modules, set the start/end levels etc and it works well. Only the submenuitems for the correct menuitem show.

I've added a CSS rule to highlight the active (sub)menuitem. When I click on a submenuitem, both the submenuitem and the menuitem are highlighted.

Great! Thanks for reading.

Hey, wait.... The menuitems always link to the same articles as their first submenuitems, so when selecting a menuitem, the first submenuitem should be highlighted as well as the menuitem, but only the latter is highlighted.

How can I get both, menuitem and first submenuitem, to be highlighted when a menuitem is clicked?

Comment: wasn't a code thing but a joomla config issue, thanks anyway @SvenBieder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... select `Menu Item Type` = `Menu Item Alias` for the menuitem!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking to create one menu with submenus; I hope this link will help you kindly let me know about your status http://help.joomla.org/content/view/1983/278/#Menu.